# Search Specific TD in Table

Tags: jquery, search, html-table

I have code to search the whole of a table, but I want to add a secondary search that will just look at the first column of the table. I'm not sure how best to adapt the code to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#glossary-table tr").not('thead tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector to get only the first td of the rows  `td:first-child`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
 
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("table tr td:first-child").not('thead tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="myInput">
```